# Sticky Footer with dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been searching for quite a while and tried several different approaches, but can't figure out a solution.

I would like for my footer to always be at the bottom of the page, however not necessarily always shown. So whenever enough posts are added, I want the page to keep growing, but the footer will always be on the bottom. You can see in my example in the snippet below how's it works.
However, I don't want the posts to be on the left side, or start from the top. Whenever I try to move the page-wrap div with absolute positioning, everything gets screwed up.

Originally inspired by this article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var post = $('.status-box').val();
  $("<li>").text(post).prependTo(".posts");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -200px;
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer,
.page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 200px;
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
.container {
  width: 520px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.button-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.counter {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.posts {
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.posts li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-height: 42px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control status-box" rows="2" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="button-group pull-right">
      <p class="counter">140</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Post</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="posts">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="site-footer">
</div>
```

Comment: If you want your footer at the bottom of the screen at all times you need position fixed

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but there's a semantic `<footer>` element

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your snippet works exactly as the CSS trick demo... can you please clarify??

Comment: @Andrew I want the footer at the bottom of the page, not the screen.

Comment: @LinkinTED Yes, the snippet does work, while the posts are in default position(To the left and starting from top). If I move them, let's say to the right and the middle, then it currently stops working.

Comment: @Hawkon, okay, I believe I understand, check my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to center your content, you can give `.page-wrap` a width and auto margin to the left and the rigth:

```
.page-wrap {
  ...
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto -200px auto;
}
```

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var post = $('.status-box').val();
  $("<li>").text(post).prependTo(".posts");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  
  width: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0 auto -200px auto;
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer,
.page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 200px;
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
.container {
  width: 520px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.button-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.counter {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.posts {
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.posts li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-height: 42px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control status-box" rows="2" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="button-group pull-right">
      <p class="counter">140</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Post</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="posts">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="site-footer">
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, that seemed to get it done. One follow up question if you don't mind. Currently the page-wrap, by default(no posts added) has a height of 978px, which makes the site longer than it otherwise has to be. If I change the min-height or add a height selector, everything screws up. Do you know any way to fix this? By the way I changed the width and margin of the page-wrap to position it where I wanted (30% & 400 100 -200 auto).

Comment: The `.page-wrapper` needs it min-height and should not have any other heights declared. You could add an extra `div` inside it and give that a height that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into it:

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/eLqzhaag/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .page-wrap {
            min-height: 100%;
            /* equal to footer height */
            position: absolute;
        }

        .page-wrap:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
        }

        .site-footer,
        .page-wrap:after {
            /* .push must be the same height as footer */
            height: 200px;
        }

        .site-footer {
            background: orange;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
        }

        .container {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .button-group {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .counter {
            display: inline;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .posts {
            clear: both;
            list-style: none;
            padding-left: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .posts li {
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            min-height: 42px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(".btn").click(function() {
            var post = $('.status-box').val();
            $("<li>").text(post).prependTo(".posts");
        });

    </script>
</head>

    <!-- language: lang-css -->


    <!-- language: lang-html -->

    <body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control status-box" rows="2" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="button-group pull-right">
                <p class="counter">140</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Post</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="posts">
            </ul>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue.

                Et mollis nunc diam eget sapien. Nulla facilisi. Etiam feugiat imperdiet rhoncus. Sed suscipit bibendum enim, sed volutpat tortor malesuada non. Morbi fringilla dui non purus porttitor mattis. Suspendisse quis vulputate risus. Phasellus erat velit, sagittis sed varius volutpat, placerat nec urna. Nam eu metus vitae dolor fringilla feugiat. Nulla.

                Facilisi. Etiam enim metus, luctus in adipiscing at, consectetur quis sapien. Duis imperdiet egestas ligula, quis hendrerit ipsum ullamcorper et. Phasellus id tristique orci. Proin consequat mi at felis scelerisque ullamcorper. Etiam tempus, felis vel eleifend porta, velit nunc mattis urna, at ullamcorper erat diam dignissim ante. Pellentesque justo risus.

                Rutrum ac semper a, faucibus nec lorem. Nullam eget quam tellus, eget sagittis justo.Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin ante enim, tincidunt ut interdum in, adipiscing quis tortor. Nulla turpis lacus, rutrum in adipiscing ut, porttitor ac ante. Sed euismod, mauris a.

                Lobortis laoreet, neque nunc suscipit orci, id ultrices nulla enim ac orci. Proin a erat at mi ornare interdum. Donec sagittis, felis at rutrum egestas, orci risus laoreet diam, quis pulvinar sapien neque id mauris. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque eget ligula ut lacus porttitor pharetra et a mauris. Cras varius gravida.

                width: 520px;
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue.

                Et mollis nunc diam eget sapien. Nulla facilisi. Etiam feugiat imperdiet rhoncus. Sed suscipit bibendum enim, sed volutpat tortor malesuada non. Morbi fringilla dui non purus porttitor mattis. Suspendisse quis vulputate risus. Phasellus erat velit, sagittis sed varius volutpat, placerat nec urna. Nam eu metus vitae dolor fringilla feugiat. Nulla.

                Facilisi. Etiam enim metus, luctus in adipiscing at, consectetur quis sapien. Duis imperdiet egestas ligula, quis hendrerit ipsum ullamcorper et. Phasellus id tristique orci. Proin consequat mi at felis scelerisque ullamcorper. Etiam tempus, felis vel eleifend porta, velit nunc mattis urna, at ullamcorper erat diam dignissim ante. Pellentesque justo risus.

                Rutrum ac semper a, faucibus nec lorem. Nullam eget quam tellus, eget sagittis justo.Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin ante enim, tincidunt ut interdum in, adipiscing quis tortor. Nulla turpis lacus, rutrum in adipiscing ut, porttitor ac ante. Sed euismod, mauris a.

                Lobortis laoreet, neque nunc suscipit orci, id ultrices nulla enim ac orci. Proin a erat at mi ornare interdum. Donec sagittis, felis at rutrum egestas, orci risus laoreet diam, quis pulvinar sapien neque id mauris. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque eget ligula ut lacus porttitor pharetra et a mauris. Cras varius gravida.

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue.


                Et mollis nunc diam eget sapien. Nulla facilisi. Etiam feugiat imperdiet rhoncus. Sed suscipit bibendum enim, sed volutpat tortor malesuada non. Morbi fringilla dui non purus porttitor mattis. Suspendisse quis vulputate risus. Phasellus erat velit, sagittis sed varius volutpat, placerat nec urna. Nam eu metus vitae dolor fringilla feugiat. Nulla.

                Facilisi. Etiam enim metus, luctus in adipiscing at, consectetur quis sapien. Duis imperdiet egestas ligula, quis hendrerit ipsum ullamcorper et. Phasellus id tristique orci. Proin consequat mi at felis scelerisque ullamcorper. Etiam tempus, felis vel eleifend porta, velit nunc mattis urna, at ullamcorper erat diam dignissim ante. Pellentesque justo risus.

                Rutrum ac semper a, faucibus nec lorem. Nullam eget quam tellus, eget sagittis justo.Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin ante enim, tincidunt ut interdum in, adipiscing quis tortor. Nulla turpis lacus, rutrum in adipiscing ut, porttitor ac ante. Sed euismod, mauris a.

                Lobortis laoreet, neque nunc suscipit orci, id ultrices nulla enim ac orci. Proin a erat at mi ornare interdum. Donec sagittis, felis at rutrum egestas, orci risus laoreet diam, quis pulvinar sapien neque id mauris. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque eget ligula ut lacus porttitor pharetra et a mauris. Cras varius gravida.

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue.

                Et mollis nunc diam eget sapien. Nulla facilisi. Etiam feugiat imperdiet rhoncus. Sed suscipit bibendum enim, sed volutpat tortor malesuada non. Morbi fringilla dui non purus porttitor mattis. Suspendisse quis vulputate risus. Phasellus erat velit, sagittis sed varius volutpat, placerat nec urna. Nam eu metus vitae dolor fringilla feugiat. Nulla.

                Facilisi. Etiam enim metus, luctus in adipiscing at, consectetur quis sapien. Duis imperdiet egestas ligula, quis hendrerit ipsum ullamcorper et. Phasellus id tristique orci. Proin consequat mi at felis scelerisque ullamcorper. Etiam tempus, felis vel eleifend porta, velit nunc mattis urna, at ullamcorper erat diam dignissim ante. Pellentesque justo risus.

                Rutrum ac semper a, faucibus nec lorem. Nullam eget quam tellus, eget sagittis justo.Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin ante enim, tincidunt ut interdum in, adipiscing quis tortor. Nulla turpis lacus, rutrum in adipiscing ut, porttitor ac ante. Sed euismod, mauris a.

                Lobortis laoreet, neque nunc suscipit orci, id ultrices nulla enim ac orci. Proin a erat at mi ornare interdum. Donec sagittis, felis at rutrum egestas, orci risus laoreet diam, quis pulvinar sapien neque id mauris. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque eget ligula ut lacus porttitor pharetra et a mauris. Cras varius gravida.



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="site-footer">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```